# Simple Python 3 Chat; Sending and receiving at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, sockets, chat

I am a total beginner in Python and today I tried to create a simple chat-program. So far it doesn't work too bad, but I am unable to communicate between the server and the client. I can only send from the server to the client but not in the other direction. I tried it with multithreading and these are the results:

**Server:**

```
import socket
import threading

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4444

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(3)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connection from: "+str(addr[0])+":"+str(addr[1]))

def recv_data():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
        print(data)

def send_data():
    while True:
        msg = input(str(socket.gethostname())+"> ")
        msg = str(host + "> ").encode('utf-8') + msg.encode('utf-8')
        conn.send(msg)

#t1 = threading.Thread(target=recv_data)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=send_data)
#t1.start()
t2.start()
```

**Client:**

```
import socket
import threading

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4444

s.connect((host, port))
print("Connected to: "+ host)

def recv_data():
    while True:
        data = s.recv(2048)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(data)

def send_data():
    while True:
        msg = input(str(host)+"> ").encode('utf-8')
        s.send(msg)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=recv_data)
#t2 = threading.Thread(target=send_data)
t1.start()
#t2.start()
```

This code works; the server can send, the client receive, but whenever I uncomment the second thread, so that it can do both I get an error:

```
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected  and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

I can't seem to find a solution, so please help, what am I doing wrong? :D

Comment: I'm not an expert, but have you tried using two different sockets (on different ports) for the two communication directions?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> conn, addr = s.accept()
>
> def recv_data():
>     while True:
>         data = s.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
>         print(data)
> ```

`conn` is actually the socket you want to `send` or `recv`. The error occurs because you are trying to `recv` from the server socket, which is illegal action. Therefore you need to change `s` to `conn` if you want to make it work.